# Why is my JS not working when set to 'onLoad' but works when set to 'No wrap - in <body>'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to get a fiddle to work how I want it, but when I'd finished I realised I had it set to '`No wrap - in <body>`' instead of '`onLoad`'.

Now I can't seem to get the margin top function to work onLoad. I can't see where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help?

Set to `No wrap - in <body>`: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/23/) (Working how I need)

Set to `onLoad`: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w5dt/22/) (Not working)

JS thats not working:

```
function extraMargin() {
   var xMar = $('.fixed-container').outerHeight(); 
   $('.scrolling-container').css({"margin-top":xMar+"px"});
}

$(window).load(function(){
   extraMargin();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
   extraMargin();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work with `onLoad` Fiddle mode because in this case your code is wrapped into `window.onload` event handler. But `window.onload` event doesn't fire twice. You put your code into `onLoad` callback in JSfiddle, and hence your own

```
$(window).load(function () {
    extraMargin();
});
```

is never executed later - there will be no additional `window.onload` to run `extraMargin` function.

You need to just have

```
//$(window).load(function () {
    extraMargin();
//});
```

if you use onLoad.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for explaining that for me. Now I understand.